# Profiling using Compuware vantage analyzer setup on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, profiling, informatica

We are trying to install compuware vantage analyzer on Informatica Application Server which internally has Tomcat Server.

I have installed console on local machine and agent on server.

and did following changes on catalina.bat file of tomcat server..

```
set PATH=C:/Compuware/VantageAnalyzer/agent/windows64;%PATH%
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -xbootclasspath/a:"C:/Compuware/VantageAnalyzer/agent/lib/VantageAnalyzerAgent.jar" -agentlib:VantageAnalyzer=agentname=XYZ
```

i.e. we have setted enviornment variable and java argument.

but we are unable to connect to Vantage Agent from our Vantage Analyzer Performance Console

Can anyone please help me over how to connect to Vantage agent from console in Tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

Compuware Product Manager here. We (Compuware) actually acquired dynaTrace in July of 2011 and have been migrating the majority of our VA customers over to it. I would strongly suggest that you reach out to hayley.hudson@compuware.com or your sales rep if you already have one for information regarding the migration process. Let me know if you have any questions.